# mongoose only insert id, createdAt and updated fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, request

I'm learning to use Node.js and MongoDB. I have a problem when I try to save data to the database.

Here's my code

```js
const Test = require('../models/test');

const test = (req, res, next) => {
    let url = "http://localhost:3000/article"
    request(url, (req, (err, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "error"

            })
        }
        var objTest = JSON.parse(fields.body);
       console.log(objTest.user)
        let test = new Test(objTest)
      console.log("ini",test)
        test
            .save()
            .then(result => {
                res.send(result)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: err
                });
            });
    }))
}
```

here my Test Schema

```js
const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    tittle: {
      type: String,
      index: true,
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
    },
    postedBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' },
    created: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema, 'tests');
```

The response in Postman is only id, createdAt and updatedAt. Thank you.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the schema definition for `Test` and the content of `fields.body`?

Comment: edited, the content is field of the data i got from the request to the url,,

Comment: No, I mean actually show the `Schema` definition code itself from `../models/test` and the actual string that's in `fields.body` in your test.

Comment: when i console the  `t let tests = new Test(objTest)`
      `console.log("ini",tests)` its return id and createdAt only

Comment: ok wait..............

Comment: editedd,,:)....

Comment: We're still missing the `fields.body` content and expected result to be able to help figure out what's wrong. Ideally, you want to provide a [MCVE] to allow others to reproduce the problem.